# How can I use Apache NiFi to retrieve attributes after splitting a JSON and use those attributes recursively in the invokeHttp processor?

Tags: json, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I'm accessing the weather data from an api and want to use Apache nifi to get the weather data for all the cities in the json array returned by the first api?

Basically I'm accessing the data through 2 APIs:

This api returns me a JSON array containing the list of all cities in USA in a JSON array element:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
        , "results": [
        {
        "name": "Keyhole",
        "city": "Keyhole",
        "state": "WY",
        "country": "US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "country_name":"USA",
        "zmw": "82721.7.99999",
        "l": "/q/zmw:82721.7.99999"
        }
        ,
        {
        "name": "Cuchara Valley Airport At La Veta",
        "city": "Cuchara Valley Airport At La Veta",
        "state": "CO",
        "country": "US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "country_name":"USA",
        "zmw": "81055.6.99999",
        "l": "/q/zmw:81055.6.99999"
        }
        ,
```

Now I want to iterate through this array and use the state and city information to be used in another API like below:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"San Francisco, CA",
        "city":"San Francisco",
        "state":"CA",
        "state_name":"California",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"94101",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"37.77500916",
        "longitude":"-122.41825867",
        "elevation":"47.00000000"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California",
        "city":"SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco",
        "state":"California",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "latitude":"37.773285",
        "longitude":"-122.417725",
        "elevation":"49 ft"
        },...
```

So basically I've to run the second api in a loop for all the combination of state and city which I'm getting from the first API.

The basic NiFi flow which I've made so far is as attached to this question but it's not working. Can someone please help me figure out what's that I'm doing wrong here?

[Hortonworks Dataflow on HDP 2.4 Sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3SzU.png)

[SplitJson Processor Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT6ra.png)

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track but for the second API call how are you supposed to designate the city/state you'd like the information for? Is it as headers, encoded in the URL or posted as the content?

Comment: I'll be using the city/state information in the URL for the second API as : api.wunderground.com/api/key/conditions/q/${state}/${city}.j‌​son, can you please suggest how to implement a loop for this processor for the different combinations of state/city I'll be getting from the first API

Comment: The flow you have in the image, with proper configuration, could be used for this application. One thing I notice is that you have all relationships (including failures and un-matched) routing in line with success. This makes it hard for you to tell what's not working. If you route failures off to another processor (like log attribute) you can see where problems lie. Also, just to be sure, many of the processor you have in the image are disabled or invalid (not configured properly) did you fix those issues
?

Comment: I really appreciate your help.The problems which I'm left now with respect to the attached dataflow are following 1) I'm splitting the first JSON returned by the first API using this JSON Path Expression in the SplitJson processor: $.response.results[*].I want to be able to use this state/city info now to be used to call the invokeHttp processor recursively(I'm not able to achieve that part yet. 2) In the end after all this is done I want to store the output using the StoreInKiteDataset processor which is not accepting Hive URI still.@JDP10101

Comment: I'll be putting answers to your problems in the answer portion below and continue to ask questions here.  When you hover over the yellow icon in the top left corner of StoreInKiteDataBase what does it say?

Comment: The error message on the StoreInKiteProcessor says - "Target Dataset URI validated against 'dataset:hive:fact_tables/ratings' is invalid because dataset URI is invalid: Unknown dataset URI: hive:fact_tables/ratings". The properties which I've set in this processor are as follows:Hadoop Configuration Files:/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml; Target Dataset URI: dataset:hive:fact_tables/ratings. Is there any documentation available on how to use a hive URI in this processor available?

Comment: I am in no ways an expert on the StoreInKiteProcessor but it does use the kite sdk for analyzing the URI. A couple examples are here: http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.1.0/URIs.html. Following the examples, this may work for you "dataset:hive:fact_tables/ratings"

Comment: I used this `*.results.*` expression in the SplitJson processor and I checked the output but it giving only one single JSON as ouput in the spilt relationship.The documentation says all the segments of the flowfile will be routed to this relationship after the split.Am I doing something wrong here?I've attached the SplitJson processor config to this thread.The URL encode is now working but this looping thing is still an issue.

Comment: Well that's odd it's only one output. Did you check provenance to see the content that's getting routed? That SplitJSON is exactly what I have. Here is a link to the template I've been testing, check it out and let me know if I'm doing something differently: https://gist.github.com/JPercivall/e243eaa73a6041c10f7a094b0fa3da1c

Comment: We are now trying to implement kerberos authentication in our HDP cluster and I'm getting this error in NiFi after the sandbox has been kerberized successfully : GetHDFS[id=9983eb5a-ce07-4d95-b8cb-91c7a3dadb77] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.io.IOException: Login failure for nifi.nifi.apache.org@HWX.COM from keytab /http-nifi.keytab; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30 sec: java.io.IOException: Login failure for nifi.nifi.apache.org@HWX.COM from keytab /http-nifi.keytab. Can you please help here?

Comment: Sorry but I have no experience using kerberos authentication. You should submit another question so that someone who does can see it. Also did my template end up working for you?

Comment: Hi,the template you provided is also not working as in the splits are not being generated.The splitJson splits the JSON doc but it creates multiple files for the first element only based on the scheduling of the processor. The other part of the JSON array element are nowhere to be seen. Also, did you find anything on the StoreInKiteDataset processor?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it creates multiple files for the first element only based on the scheduling of the processor". The processor will only create the splits when it is run, so you will need to set a scheduling period faster than your data is coming in (leaving at 0 is normally fine) and what is an "element" in this context?  I didn't know you had more problems with StoreInKiteDataset processor, did the example URI I provided not work?

Comment: I meant it is only giving one single flow file after the SplitJson processor whereas it should be generating multiple flow files with each flow file containing the data for each element(city details) from the JSON array which is returned from the first API.Currently it produces only one single flow file after the SplitJson which only has the details of the first element of the JSON array[i.e. results in this case]. In the StoreInKiteDataset processor also the same error still exists "Target Dataset URI validated against 'dataset:hive:fact_tables/ratings' is invalid...".

Comment: Hi, did you find anything on the splitJson processor issue? @JDP10101

Comment: When you imported the Template, did you just run it by itself to see how the configured SplitJSON creates multiple elements? I'm having trouble figuring out why the template would correctly create and split the JSON on my system but not on yours.

Comment: Hi, is there any chance we can do a join.me meeting? Any time which suits you. Just want to close this once and for all and I'll also get to know if there's anything which I'm doing wrong here. Please let me know if it's possible, I'll share a meeting link with you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Answering the problems exposed in comments:

For the SplitJSON the JSON path expression you want to use is `*.results.*` this will split the JSON into a FlowFile per result. The EvaluateJSONPath configuration you have should work with an updated SplitJSON (just tested in a template).

The Expression Language (EL) you provided for the InvokeHttp URL is almost there. One thing you will need is to URL encode the city and state using the EL "urlEncode" like so: `api.wunderground.com/api/key/conditions/q/${state:urlEncode()}/${city:urlEncode()}.j‌​son`